# How can I get the group identifier from .client.addMessage

Tags: c#, asp.net, real-time, signalr

I need to get the group identifier and message on the function callback. Is it possible?

Here's the code:

```
$(function () {
    // Proxy created on the fly          
    var chat = $.connection.discussion;
    var discussionId = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    alert(discussionId);
    var discussionId2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    alert(discussionId2);
    $.connection.hub.start(function () {
        chat.server.join(discussionId);
        chat.server.join(discussionId2);
    });

    // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it          
    chat.client.addMessage = function (message) {
        $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
    };

    // Start the connection
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        $("#broadcast").click(function () {
            // Call the chat method on the server
            var discussionIdX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
            alert(discussionIdX);
            chat.server.send(discussionIdX, $('#msg').val());
        });
    });
});
```

It's just an example. Basically I add the user to 2 random groups and then I need to I need the group identificator to append the message to the correct div.

Edited:

```
    public class Discussion : Hub{
public void Send(string discussionId, string message)
{
    Clients.Group(discussionId).addMessage(message);
}

public void Join(string discussionId)
{
    Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, discussionId);
}}
```

Comment: Please include some server-side code that's calling `addMessage`.

Comment: I updated the post with server code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the group as a parameter from the server.

On the client:

```
chat.client.addMessage = function (message, group) { ... }
```

and on the server:

```
Clients.Group(discussionId).addMessage(message, discussionId);
```

Comment: But how? I updated the post with the server code! How do I set the function I create on the server as the callback?